# Ubuntu 12.04 freeze on Ctrl+ALT+F1

Tags: 12.04, freeze, virtual-terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I have Radeon card connected over HDMI to my TV.

To resolve bug with HDMI-sound, I switch between virtual terminal and GNOME desktop each time the TV is switched on with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and after console appear with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. It's ugly, but its worked for me.

Since yesterday I got system freezes on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - no reaction on keyboard, mouse pointer disappear at all, GNOME desktop still displayed. Probably has nothing to do with HDMI.

Any suggestion how to resolve it?